# Beamer metropolis theme: How to add smoothbars progress indicators?

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

Is there a ready way to add the smoothbars subsection progress dots to metropolis?

Alternatively, is there a different minimalist theme that easily incorporates smoothbars? Thx

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load the `miniframes` outer theme after the other theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=mDarkTeal}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip-0.01cm}{}

\begin{document}

\section{section}   
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]